# Call up a function from another module

Tags: function, python-3.x, import, module, tkinter

I am making a project where I need several modules which are imported into one main module. I have decided to move the interaction to a single Tkinter window. Instead of using `input()` I use `tkinter.Entry()`, for example. I have functions for each step of the interaction.

When I get past the last function of the first module, the configured button has a command to go to a function in the second module. I get an error saying that the command is not defined.

I seem unable to import the configured button variable into the next module, and anything else I tried gave no result. It simply doesn't go to the next module after the first module is done.

I have made the main Tkinter window in the main module and have it that it will `mainloop` after importing the other modules. Shouldn't the function I want to call upon be defined? How can I get from one function to the next if the latter is in a separate module?

---

Here is a minimal example:

**main_script.py**

```
import tkinter
mainwindow = tkinter.Tk()
# here i set the window to a certain size etc.
import mod1
import mod2
mainwindow.mainloop()
```

**mod1.py**

```
import tkinter
def button1():
    label.destroy()
    button1.destroy()
    button2.config(text = "continue", command = func2)
def button2():
    label.destroy()
    button1.destroy()
     button2.config(text = "continue", command = func2)
label = tkinter.Label(text = "example label")
button1 = tkinter.Button(text = "button1", command = button1)
button2 = tkinter.Button(text = "button2", command = button2)
label.pack()
button1.pack()
button2.pack()
```

**mod2.py**

```
def func2():
    button2.destroy()
    print ("haha it works...")
```

Comment: Try to strip your code down to [the bare minimum that runs and reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Take out everything that isn't necessary to see the bug, then post it. As well as helping us see what the problem is, isolating it in this manner is likely to help you solve it yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you very much for the attention to the code. I would also strip out the less relevant portions of the text, though.

Comment: Ok thanks,two good comments, I see how this makes a better question than my original one. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing a module has no effect on what the module you import can see. If you want to use `mod1` contents in `mod2` and `mod2` contents in `mod1`, you need to have them import each other and refer to each other's contents with the appropriate module:

```
# mod1
import mod2
...
    button2.config(text = "continue", command = mod2.func2)

# mod2
import mod1
def func2():
    mod1.button2.destroy()
```

Circular imports cause nasty initialization order issues, though, so imports like this are a bad idea. When dividing your code into modules, try to do so in such a way that import loops like this aren't necessary.

Comment: Thats a pretty good solution, it works well on the example code and should do what I need it to, and nice heads up at the bottom, thanks.